# MySql.ConnectorNET.Data vs MySql.Data

Tags: mysql, .net, nuget, mysql-connector, connector-net

What is the difference between the [MySql.ConnectorNET.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.ConnectorNET.Data/) and the [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) packages on NuGet?

They both appear to be published by the same user ([MySQL](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/MySQL)), and the `Project Site` links point to the same location (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).

After installing both, the ConnectorNET version appears to lag behind the other version by a release.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the time you asked this question, Oracle (the package owner) has made the situation clear:

- [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) is the official package that continues to be updated.
- [MySql.ConnectorNET.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.ConnectorNET.Data/) now has no published releases. It shows the warning: “The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.”

NuGet also has the following other MySQL ADO.NET connectors:

- [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) — community-developed OSS connector library supporting async and .NET Core.
- [SapientGuardian.MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SapientGuardian.MySql.Data/) — started as a fork of `MySql.Data` that added `netstandard1.3` support; now unmaintained.
- [dotConnect.Express.for.MySQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotConnect.Express.for.MySQL/) — free “Express Edition” of a closed-source commercial product offering [paid editions](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/editions.html).

  - [Devart.Data.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.MySql/) —  the commercial edition.
- [CData.MySQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CData.MySQL/) — closed-source commercial product that requires a [paid license](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/mysql/order/).
- [Xamarin.MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.MySql.Data/) — fork of MySql.Data.CF.dll (Compact Framework) 6.9.5 for MonoTouch and MonoAndroid; now unmaintained.

Comment: Is it ok to use MySqlConnector if application using DB First Entity Framework? What other packages needs to install?

Comment: @HimalayaGarg There is no EF library based on MySqlConnector. For EF Core, use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.