# What is the difference between Oracle mysqld.data.dll and MariaDB mysql.data.dll for c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

With c# can I use the mysqld.data.dll provided by Oracle to use on MariaDb Mysql database? Is there much difference?

Comment: The backend (base class) is the same for all database.  But each type database has unique features.  In c# your read write to classes (common) but then a driver (dll) is used to interface to a particular type database.

Comment: [MariaDB versus MySQL: Compatibility](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any "mysqld.data.dll" provided by Oracle; are you referring to the [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data) NuGet package, or something else?

See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47188234) for an overview of all MySQL ADO.NET libraries for .NET.

For a connector specifically for MariaDB, I would recommend [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/). As well as being MIT-licensed and fully supporting async I/O, it supports MariaDB-specific features such as `client_ed25519` authentication, GSSAPI authentication, `COM_MULTI` batched commands, and more.