# MySQL Nuget Packages Difference

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

Hi gurus of Stack Overflow

My random question of the day is what are main differences between the Nuget packages MySql.Data and MySql.EntityFrameworkCore?

I understand that the EntityFrameworkCore package allows you to use EF with MySQL, so I'm naturally assuming that MySql.Data is aimed more along the lines of inline SQL. Bearing in mind that you can still do inline queries using the EntityFrameworkCore package, without actually using EF... which makes me question the need for MySql.Data at all, assuming my assumptions are correct (which they are most likely not)

So for varying hypothetical reasons (can't think of any right now), let's say that inline SQL is your only option. Which package would be the better option in that case, and why?

I tried to Google the differences between the 2 packages but didn't get any clear explanations of the differences.

Comment: MySql.EntityFrameworkCore uses MySql.Data. They both target different audiences, with different needs. If I'm not using EF Core, I wouldn't want to pull all of its dependencies into my project.

Comment: _"Bearing in mind that you can still do inline queries using the EntityFrameworkCore package, without actually using EF"_ - eh, what?

Comment: @Dai The OP may be referring to the ability to send a literal SQL query using `.FromSql()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries

Comment: For a comparison of other MySQL NuGet packages, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47188234/23633.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi gurus of Stack Overflow

If we're using religious metaphors, then I'm more of a *self-flagellator* than a *guru*.

> I understand that the EntityFrameworkCore package allows you to use EF with MySQL, so I'm naturally assuming that MySql.Data is aimed more along the lines of inline SQL

I have no idea what you mean by "inline SQL" - because that *simply isn't a thing*.

> Bearing in mind that you can still do inline queries using the EntityFrameworkCore package, without actually using EF...

I think what you're describing is how you're able to use the lower-level `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` types from your project even though you only made a `<PackageReference>` to `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore`? If so, then you are mistaken: `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore` *depends on* `MySql.Data`, so you're able to use those types due to how .NET makes references *kinda*-transitively.

> I tried to Google the differences between the 2 packages but didn't get any clear explanations of the differences.

That's because you can't compare the two packages like that: one package **depends upon the other**, which means they aren't directly comparable as alternatives to each other (because they aren't).

---

- Entity Framework is an ORM.
- ORMs generally don't concern themselves with *low-level* data-access details - that's the realm of *four-letter words* like ODBC, JDBC, OLE-DB, ADO.NET, etc.
- But because ORMs need to support all the main features of all the main RDBMS it means ORMs will always need the help of database-specific "driver" or "provider" libraries which do the job of handling vendor-specific aspects (like SQL code-generation) which are outside the scope of the lower-level OLE-DB/ODBC/ADO.NET providers.
- The `MySql.Data` package is the "*low-level*" library that holds the **ADO.NET Provider** (i.e. the MySQL-specific subclasses of `System.Data.DbConnection`, `DbCommand`, `DbDataReader`, et cetera) .
- The `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore` package is a *higher-level* library that serves as an adapter between Entity Framework (your ORM) and the lower-level `MySql.Data` ADO.NET-level library).

Comment: By "inline SQL", I think he might mean "raw SQL": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries. EF Core allows `.FromSql()` which allows a literal SQL expression without dropping down to `MySqlCommand`. So the transitive nature of .NET packages isn't related to this.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger ah yes... that's exactly what I meant :D Apologies for the terminology mix up O.o I don't always get the right words for the things bouncing around in my head :P

Comment: @Dai lmao XD self-flagellator... duly noted ;)
And thank you for the fantastic explanation... helped a lot :)